# Reply to emails automatically

Tags: email, html-email, sendgrid

I want to setup an email address that my customers can email to, for which then they receive an automated html email reply.  I don't need to store these emails anywhere, I just want something that can automatically reply.  This isn't like an out-of-office response as this will need to be a custom HTML (with images) formatted email.

What's the best way to go about this without having to set-up any infrastructure (e.g servers, write code)?  Is there some online service that can do this for me?

Comment: most email services allow you to set up auto reply's what do you have so far, who is currently provind your email services? what have you set up/tried so far?

Comment: The email provider is 123-reg. They do have a auto-responder function, but this is only allows replying with plain text emails.

Comment: Then you could forward those incoming mails to a provider who offers the feature you need here, so html emails. Though I would generally advise against the use of html emails...

Comment: I haven't been able to find any email provider that does this.

Comment: MailChimp has a paid service, but I've never used it.  http://mailchimp.com/features/automation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this with SendGrid's Inbound Parse Webhook pretty easily, you can modify this autoreply with a business card example that I wrote to do exactly what you need. Just follow the steps: https://sendgrid.com/blog/oh-cardless-business-card-email-app/

If you wanted more control over the content of the email without having to redeploy an app every time then you can also use [SendGrid's Template Engine](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-template-engine).

Here's an example of the same business card reply app from above, but this time using Template Engine: https://sendgrid.com/blog/migrating-app-sendgrids-template-engine/

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks